Recommendations for Practical Books on Stochastic Volatility and Portfolio Optimization
I’m an engineering student nearing graduation with an MSc in Applied Mathematics. I've studied Monte Carlo methods, time series analysis, and stochastic calculus, with a focus on portfolio optimization and options in my student projects. I came across this post with a great list of book recommendations: What are the quantitative finance books that we should all have in our shelves?. However, I'm specifically looking for books that focus on project-like exercises where you apply Monte Carlo methods, time series analysis, and similar techniques to solve practical problems. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

https://www.amazon.com/dp/047005316X ?

Thank you! I will have a look!

look also at http://dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.2473289

time-series wise, what you're looking for is kind of rare but this book is well known for its case studies. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118150528

Thank you Mark, I will try to get ahold of it! Thank you Dimitri, this paper looks very relevant!

maybe try to get a look before you purchase it because it's kind of specific ( mostly ARMAs or ARDLs ) and may be too narrow in its coverage ? Time-series books with practical problems are a good idea but difficult to find. Another one to check out ( with the same disclaimer ) is this: amazon.com/Introductory-Econometrics-Finance-Chris-Brooks/dp/…
